# How to get the authorization code from redirect uri using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

So Im trying to create login system with AWS Cognito and then use the access key to access all the API that are going to be used within my application. I already set up the AWS cognito and able to redirect from login page of the hosted UI to callback URL with the access code because I'm using Authorization code grant type of oauth flows.

However in order to get the access key I need the access code from the redirect URL which I don't know how to get them from the URL. Could anyone help me with that?

https://example.com/callback?code=XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX

that is an example of the redirect URL yet I'm trying to get the XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX with python.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing

Comment: I find a solution to the same problem as you , if you solve this please reply to me ....